# What tag should be used for MMO questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

What tag should be used for Massively Multiplayer Online Games?

Options that come to mind:

### mmo

Most common? Combined with **rpg** for games that are both.

### mmorpg

Also common. In contrast to tagging both **mmo** and **rpg**.

### massively-multiplayer

More verbose suggestion. It has been pointed out that although recognisable and in the spirit of minimising abbreviations, it is technically incorrect - as one could have a massively-multiplayer game that was not online.

### mmog

More correct. [Removed as the **g** is basically implied.]

Comment: don't forget MMOFPS and MMORTS

Comment: Any more input / votes? We don't really seem to have consensus at the moment.

Comment: As we don't have a consensus yet, I think it would be prudent to unaccept my answer until there is a consensus.  There seems to be tag-editing wars going on at the moment due to this question. (See FallenAngelEyes' answer)

Comment: Unaccepted as per @Michael Herold's comment.

Answer (score 5):

To me, having the tag be [massively-multiplayer] makes it too unwieldy.  As such, I was thinking something similar to Arda Xi's comment:

- **MMO** for any massively multiplayer game
- **Second Genre-Specific Tag** based on the genre of the game

So it would look something like this:

- Planetside would have two tags: *MMO* and *FPS*
- WoW would have two tags: *MMO* and *RPG*

This would allow people to find games in each of the sub-genres of MMO by searching for that genre's tag (i.e. Planetside is findable under FPS and WoW is findable under RPG). The search is easily configurable enough to allow someone to easily find MMORPGS by including [mmo] [rpg] in their search.  To me, the benefits overwhelm the costs.

Comment: Actually, searching for mmo (non-tag) will find posts tagged [mmorpg], while searching for mmorpg (non-tag) will not find posts tagged [mmo] [rpg] [more...](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/152/what-tag-should-be-used-for-mmo-questions/614#614)

Comment: I did say that in my original comment: "In that case I'd just suggest MMO for all, and possibly MMORPG for specific RPGs as an additional tag"

Comment: But why would you be searching for mmorpg (non-tag)?  To me, you would only do this search if you were looking for a question along the lines of "What is an MMORPG?" or similar questions.  The point I was going for in my answer was that people who are interested in RPGs might be interested in MMORPGs as well, so why not allow the clumping?

Comment: Actually, searching for rpg (non-tag) will find posts tagged [mmorpg], while searching for mmorpg (non-tag) will not find posts tagged [mmo] [rpg]

Comment: But again, why would somebody be searching for "rpg"? If you can point out why such a search would be useful, then I'll be happy to back your idea. Such a search is part of the reason tagging was invented; it's a taxonomy for questions/discussion that allows one to quickly narrow a search. I still feel that having the two tags fits the needs of the asker more than having one.

Comment: ***Don't ask why*** there will be searched for, ***ask what gives the best results,*** "mmorpg" not returning `[mmo]` `[rpg]` tagged questions or "rpg" returning `[mmorpg]` tagged questions.

Also, remember, noobs might not be aware that they can use tags in the search,

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using `[mmorpg]` for those games instead of the combination of `[mmo]` and `[rpg]` for  several reasons:

- The genre is largest subgenre in both rpg and mmo, being even bigger than the rest of the genre in the latter case. (There are more active mmorpg players than non-rpg mmo players)
- Giving a dedicated tag for mmorpg ensures both the `[mmo]` (non-rpg) tag, as well as the `[rpg]` (non-mmo) tag doesn't get flooded by mmorpg questions.
- Remember, MMORPGs are an over $1 billion dollar industry! [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MMORPG)
- Are we going to tag action-adventures with both `[action]` and `[adventure]`
- It saves us a tag on those posts (we have a tag limit of 5)
- we don't have an easy way to filter the non-mmo questions from the rpg questions (for newbies), while the `[mmorpg]` tag is easily found
- MMORPGs have unique elements, not seen in other mmo or rpg games. (guilds doing quests)
- searching for `[mmo]` `[rpg]` instead of `[mmorpg]` is counterintuitive for new users.
- Actually, searching for mmo (non-tag) will find posts tagged `[mmorpg]`, while **searching for mmorpg (non-tag) will not find posts tagged `[mmo]` `[rpg]`**

BTW: didn't we agree to reserve the genre tags for the specific genres and not use them for the games, only for the genre questions.? (can't find meta-post now.)

(and for those saying MMORPG is not a proper name, [wikipedia seems to disagree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MMORPG))

Comment: The point about the 5 tag limit is valid, but I don't really see it being a problem for the overwhelming majority of questions. There's a reason the limit is 5; beyond that, you're spending more time classifying a question than asking or answering it.

Comment: Would be interested if anyone is able to dig up that meta post WRT not tagging games with their genres.

Answer (score 2):

Since not all massively-multiplayer games are RPGs, then I'd say:

- **MMORPG** for massively-multiplayer RPGs
- I suggest **massively-multiplayer** for massively-multiplayer games that aren't RPGs, though **MMO** is also nice.

MMOG is a bit redundant since this is a gaming site :) and anyway I think MMO is more common.

Now, it's true that there are some terms such as MMORTS and MMOFPS lying around, and they may even be pretty accurate for describing some games, but I'm not sure they are well-known enough to warrant their own tag.

Comment: In that case I'd just suggest MMO for all, and possibly MMORPG for specific RPGs as an additional tag.

Answer (score 1):

While I usually prefer things written out to abbreviations, I strongly recommend **MMO** to the alternatives.  In fact, I'd go so far as to say **MMORPG** is wrong.

While we often refer to games as being MMORPGs, they are in fact both an MMO and a RPG.  These are two different genre which should both be tagged.  If I want to look for RPGs I should see games which are both MMO and not.

Comment: What are your thoughts on MMO vs. massively-multiplayer?

Comment: Massively Multiplayer is technically a different genre than MMO.  It is possible to have Massively Multiplayer games which communicate asynchronously (and thus are not "online").  They're rare enough that we could group them together, but I think that MMO is a more appropriate term in this instance, as that's usually what people are referring to.  [Massively-Multiplayer-Online] is probably too long for a tag.

Answer (score 1):

I think both tags have their relevance. I posted a question asking for a game and tagged it MMO because I didn't care if it was an RPG. So the tag MMORPG would not have accurately described my question but would definitely be more appropriate for something like: "Games similar to WoW?"

I personally like the idea of splitting the MMO away from RPG, FPS and so on for the reasons Michael Herold and tzenes mentioned. But I think things would work just as well without that split up.

Edit: The tag "massively-multiplayer" is too verbose IMO. Nobody calls it that unless they have to explain their hobby to some outsider.

Answer (score 0):

I went through and tagged all the [world-of-warcraft] questions to follow the tagging scheme Michael Herold suggested ([mmo] and [rpg]), but alexanderpas has changed them to [mmorpg]. There doesn't seem to be a way to message users to talk to them, so posting here I guess.

Comment: [Response posted](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/152/what-tag-should-be-used-for-mmo-questions/614#614)

Comment: While we all appreciate work to create a cohesive tagging system, I feel it was in bad form for @alexanderpas to retag many questions with his/her idea immediately after introducing it, and contrary to the current 'consensus'.

Comment: actually, I wasn't aware of this question over here. I actually retagged in good faith before noticing this question and posting it here. (as i consider `[mmo]` `[rpg]` [slightly harmful](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/152/what-tag-should-be-used-for-mmo-questions/614#614) )