# Do we use abbreviations in genre names? [Completed]

Tags: discussion, tags

I know this has been asked about games, but what about genres?

<del>[[rts]](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rts) - 4 (one closed)</del> - 0
[[real-time-strategy]](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-time-strategy) - <del>3</del> 7

[[tbs]](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tbs) - 0
[[turn-based-strategy]](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/turn-based-strategy) - 8

[[rpg]](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rpg) - 6
[[mmorpg]](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mmorpg) - 6
Longer forms - 0
(leave alone as per answers)

[[first-person-shooter]](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-person-shooter) - <del>1</del> 18
[[fps]](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fps) - <del>18</del> 0

For SEO purposes, the full names might be preferable. But at the very least, some consensus would be nice.

Comment: Aren't [rpg] and [mmorpg] different things?

Comment: MMORPG's are a subset of RPGs.

Comment: BTW - I've renamed [first-person] to [first-person-shooter] as [shooter] was a separate tag and the OP probably just missed the "-" out.

Comment: kk, And I've retagged all the [rts] questions.

Comment: OK - I've retagged all but one of the [fps] questions as it seems to relate to frames per second. Not sure what to retag it to though.

Comment: @Grace - no, that's a new one. I meant this one - http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1644/is-ship-turn-rate-still-limited-by-the-viewport-what-ships-turn-faster-if-you

Comment: @ChrisF I see 4 questions still with the tag. Which is the one you're referring to?

Comment: @ChrisF That question is not about frames-per-second, but first-person-view (not unlike some games like Armored Core 3: Silent Line, where you could choose both third-person view and first-person view). I would suggest adding both [first-person-view] and [third-person-view], perhaps. Or viewpoint. Quite frankly, [allegience] is confusing me because it was also marked as an RTS. It seems to be one of those baffling multi-genre games.

Comment: @Grace - I did a search for "crysis" and 2 came up. I don't know why they don't appear in the tag search. Done now. If you find any more let me know.

Comment: @Grace - Sounds good to me. Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one good reason that abbreviations in genres are dangerous, look at FPS. Miraculously, we have not actually run into any problem with it, but it's only a matter of time before the people asking about frames-per-second decide to lazy it up and tag it FPS. Which is sad, because both meaning of FPS are very critical in the gaming community.

Not to mention, some days I don't even know what the abbreviation stands for, even for my favorite genres like STG.

So for consistency's sake, I think we should think about moving over to expanded names. Once again, it's more clearly understood, and indeed it helps with searches. But unlike game titles, I don't think we need to [clarify the acronyms as often in the post body](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/410/game-abbreviations-in-regards-to-search-engines/416#416). What a genre abbreviation stands for is understood by a much larger fraction of the gaming community, and for tagging we have auto-complete.

For MMORPG, see [What tag should be used for MMO questions?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152/what-tag-should-be-used-for-mmo-questions)

Comment: "Some days I don't even know what the abbreviation stands for, even for my favorite genres like STG" That's what tag wiki's should be for...

Comment: @badp I believe that tag wikis should be used because people get confused by tags, not that we should confuse people with tags because we have tag wikis.

Comment: Just to revive this, we currently have trouble with inconsistency between RPG and RTS. We should either stick to one strategy or the other, right now RTS is a synonym for real-time-strategy and RPG is the other way around.

Comment: @Arda See: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/671/why-do-we-have-rpg-and-first-person-shooter.

Answer (score 1):

don't use abbreviations, except where the abbreviation itself has become a stand-alone word (basically, AFAIK only `[rpg]` applies.)

shorthand trick: try adding games to it.

- RPG games (note the [RAS syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAS_syndrome) here)
- Turn-based Strategy Games (and not TBS games)
- Real-time Strategy Games (and not RTS games, to match with the previous.)